# Is there a way to convert COM interface GUIDs to the string name of the interface?

Tags: c++, com

For debugging purposes, I would like to display the queried interface name. I can search for the GUID by hand in Google, but it's very slow. Is there a function that does this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690567.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682271.aspx perhaps? And what about interfaces that don't register names?

Comment: The debugger already does this, as long as the interface guid appears in the registry.  HKCR\Interface key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write one.  Just look up your GUID in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Paul Mitchell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11099985/140367), here is my implementation (for Qt):

```
QSettings s(QString("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\Interface\\{%1}").arg(str_guid), QSettings::NativeFormat);
qDebug() << "Querying interface:" << std_guid << "called" << s.value("Default").toString();
```